# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo using TextView

Tags: android

I am making a File IO Project and I am having a problem with my component view.  I know it has something with my TextView but I am a newbie and cant figure it out.  Here is the code below:

```
package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Main extends Activity {
    public TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations();
        Testing testing = new Testing();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        testing.checkExternalMedia();
        //fileOperations.CreateFile("example.txt");



    }



}
```

Here is the Log for it:

```
    02-13 19:54:47.199: W/dalvikvm(1533): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):  {com.IPR2.viewlog/com.IPR2.viewlog.ViewLog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.IPR2.viewlog.Testing.checkExternalMedia(Testing.java:43)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.IPR2.viewlog.ViewLog.onCreate(ViewLog.java:31)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-13 19:54:47.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     ... 11 more
```

I am using another class and calling tv.append ("File not saved!") as debugging.  If I comment it out the problem goes away.  I think Im handling it incorrectly and know it should be easy to fix.  I know I can debug using other ways, but I would like to learn how to do it this way as I would like to never get this error again :]

```
package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileOperations extends Main{



        public void CreateFile(String fileName)
        {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Nullwall");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            tv.append("\nLog File Created In Directory: " + root);
            File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
            writer.write("");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " Log Successfully Created!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv.append(" \n File not Saved! CreateLogFile() Broken!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is something really not good in the design, why FileOperations extending Main?

Comment: Like I said, newbie! I was trying to get tv to work.  Any suggestions on how you would do it? I am always trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Main extends Activity {
    public TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations();
        Testing testing = new Testing();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        //testing.checkExternalMedia();
        createFile("example.txt");
    }


    public void createFile(String fileName)
    {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Nullwall");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            tv.append("\nLog File Created In Directory: " + root);
            File gpxfile = new File(root, fileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
            writer.write("");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " Log Successfully Created!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv.append(" \n File not Saved! CreateLogFile() Broken!");
        }
}
```

I do not know if this code is working. But it should be. So now I'll try to explain it.
If you create a TextView object tv, then you should refer to it from the same class (or you can produce a method to get access to it).

Second, you should improve your architecture. If a class called FileOperations then I expect to see there methods and fields to work with files. FileOperations is not a proper place for updating UI.

Third, if there is only one method why you create a separate class for it?

The problem in your code is that tv cannot be accessed from your derived class.

Comment: The Class file operations has many different methods; I isolated an example problem to demonstrate the problem.  I have several classes, all with tv in it.  I understand this answer should work as well if I wanted a single classs, but as I have around 20 other methods in 4 other classes, I would like a way to:

''
`1. Use tv.append as shown in a different class as above.  If this cannot be done or should not be done, could you offer an example of how to throw errors in a similiar way? Thank You!`

Comment: You cannot have access to your TextView. You can, for instance, get the text to be appended as a return statement if you want to separate classes. But do not extend Main class - it mess your project alot.

Comment: Alright! How can I add something simple to say "This is broken, Fix it!" that is easy and will show up in the program?

Comment: I am now using the Log.d("Class_where_logs_happening","Message about log");  It works. Thank you for the help.  I stopped extending my main as well.

Comment: Now I've catch that you use this just for debugging ))) This changes the situation. Sorry, I did not understand your question clearly at first )